# Binomial Expansion

Tags: binomial-theorem

Let $f, g:[0,1]\rightarrow R$ be functions such that $$\left\{\begin{array} & f(x)=g(x)=0 & \Leftrightarrow x=1 \\
f(x), g(x) \neq 0 & \Leftrightarrow x \neq 1\end{array}\right.$$
Now consider the Binomial expansion of 
\begin{equation}
h(x,y)=xy\big[1+f(x)g(y)\big]^{n},
\end{equation}
where $n \in \mathbb{N}$:
\begin{align}
h(x,y)=&xy\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}\left[f(x)g(y)\right]^r\\
=&xy +xy\sum_{r=1}^{n}\binom{n}{r}\left[f(x)g(y)\right]^r.
\end{align}
Is this expansion valid? Since, for $r=0, x=1$, $[f(x)]^r$ becomes of the form $0^{0}$. Is there any restriction on $f$ and $g$ when making such expansions?

Comment: This is expansion of $(1+x)^{n}$ form not of the $(a+b)^{n}$ form. The question is that for $r=0$, what we have to write?

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks what the first term is of 
$$f(x,y)=xy\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r}[f(x)g(y)]^r$$ 
When $x=1$ and $f(1)=0$.

To simplify the question, let us look at the power of a binomial $$(1+\lambda)^n$$ where $\lambda = f(x)g(y)$ and the expression is divided by $xy$. The first term of the expansion, no matter what power is chosen, will equal $1$. In particular, when $\lambda =0$,
$$(1+0)^n=1^n=1$$
Thus, the term $\lambda^0$ in the binomial expansion is equal to $1$ even if $\lambda=0$.